# .feature file in cypress cucumber , stopped running tests because a plugin crashed

Tags: plugins, crash, cucumber, cypress, bdd

I am trying to run a .feature file in cypress cucumber. but when i run the file, getting this error.

TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'name' of '(intermediate value).parse(...).feature' as it is undefined.

following is my index.js

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />

/**
 * @type {Cypress.PluginConfig}
 */ 

const cucumber = require('cypress-cucumber-preprocessor').default

module.exports = (on, config) => {

  on('file:preprocessor', cucumber())

}
```

Can anyone please tell me what am i doing wrong?is

Comment: Most likely to happen when your feature files not in the proper gherkin format

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, the problem was there was a feature file without the word "feature" inside. I was not using that file because it was commented but cypress ask me for that word.

Answer (score 1):

Change in your file .feature `Scenario :` for `Scenario Outline:`  and run

Comment: Can you offer more detail? For instance, some broader context, and why this will fix the issue?

Comment: Yes, of course, because when the  keyword "scenario"  is used, cucumber does not expect input parameters for the test, you need use "outline" keyword after the scenario so that cucumber understands that we will use examples tables to use additional parameters.